# Apply conditional class in a rails view inside map{} using haml

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, haml

I am trying to apply a class conditionally to the names associated with a reminder. If there are three persons associated with a reminder - Jay, Jonah and Jamison... and Jonah is the one who acknowledged the reminder, then I want his name to have the class "acknowledge", though I want to display all three names.

```
%tbody
  -reminder.each do |r|
    %tr
      %td 
        =r.persons.each.map{|n| n.name{:class=> ("acknowledge" if r.completed_by.id == n.id)} }.join(',')
```

I tried to apply the class inside the map{} as shown above but get an error saying

`syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}'`

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%tbody
  - reminder.each do |r|
    %tr
      %td 
        - r.persons.each do |person|
          %span{class: "acknowledge" if person.completed_by.id == n.id}= person.name
```

Comment: Thanks @Yury  This worked perfectly.  One thing I lose with this is the absence of comma between names.  I can put it with some logic to avoid it for the last name.